# Sytem shuts down on inserting a metal pen drive

Tags: usb, usb-flash-drive

I have a desktop with windows 8 OS. Many times ( remember, not always) when I insert my HP pendrive in to the port, the system shuts down. The pendrive has a metallic cover. Then I reboot with the pendrive in the port and all is well. This never happened with any other pendrive with plastic cover. This happens only in my home system and not in my office system. Any ideas ?

Comment: Sounds like the HP pendrive is creating a short. This can damage your motherboard so be careful.

Comment: cover the metal with tape.

Comment: You have a poorly designed desktop computer, with serious disregard of ESD grounding/shielding. You can verify that by moving yourself over carpet back-forth and then touching the USB port shield with a metal object in your hand, screwdriver or something.